# Sublime Text 3 displaying character wrongly after nesting a function

Tags: macos, fonts, sublimetext, visual-glitch

So I'm running Sublime Text 3 on OS X with Boxy Theme and Monokai-Cobalt color scheme.
I noticed that when I fold a function (by clicking the arrow in the line number) it displays the following character (?):

[image: sublime Text 3 nested function character]

For what I know it should be displaying an ellipsis character, but I'm not sure.

I tried changing my font, changing the color scheme, changing theme, even disabling bracket highlighter. Still the same. Does anyone knows what could be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this image depend of the **theme** you're using, unfortunately not the color scheme.

I guess that if it has worked after, it's because changing the theme has reloaded the theme, so the image...

By the way, it's not a char, it's the "image" Sublime Text uses when there is no image specified for it, or when ST cannot access the it.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

The problem went away after I changed to Sublime Text's default theme, and then back again to Boxy.